# Who are saryuparin brahmins?

Tags: caste-system, brahmins

Some say that saryuparin is a sub-caste of kanyekubja while some say both are very different.

Is there any origin story? And how are the saryuparins identified?

Answer (score 2):

Well excerpts from wiki shows that [Saryupareen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saryupareen_Brahmin) are basically a branch of Kanyakubja family:

> "Kanyakubj Vanshavali" mentions five branches of Kanyakubja Brahmins
> as **Saryupareen**, Sanadhya, Bhumihar Brahmin, Jujhautiya and Prakrit
> Kanaujia:
>
> ```
> Saryupari Sanadhyashcha Bhumiharo Jijhoutayah
> Prakritashcha Iti Panchabhedastasya Prakartitah.
> ```
>
> **These five branches make up the Kanyakubja Brahmin class**, a subset of
> the overall Brahmin caste.

Origin of Kanyakubj Brahmins (Saryupareen are part of it) as explained [here](http://kanyakubj.in/origin-of-kanyakubj-brahmins):

> There was the a son of Lord Brahma called KUSH. Kush had four sons
> named as KUSHABH, KUSHNABH, ASHRUTRAJAS and VASU. Kushnabh had one
> hundred extremely beautiful daughters through Ghritachee, an Apsara.
> The god of Vaayu (Air) was very much attracted by the beauty of these
> fair ladies & wanted to marry  with them. These virgins told god Vaayu
> that they were the daughters of a rishi and they would marry with only
> that person as advised by their father and humbly denied the proposal
> of  god Vaayu to marry with him. The god Vaayu was annoyed and cursed
> all these beautiful virgin daughters of Kushnabh become Hunchbacked or
> to become Kubja.  These virgin hunchback daughters of Kushnabh were
> married with Brahma Dutta, the noble king of Kampilya,  son of Choolie
> Rishi and Somada Gandharvee. As soon as, these virgin daughters of
> Kushnabh were touched by noble King Brahma Dutta, all these virgins
> were free from curse of god Vaayu. They became normal, their bumps
> were vanished and they regained their original beauty and charm.
>
> Kampilya the kingdom of Brahmdutt later became famous by name of
> KANYAKUBJA (because he married the kubja daughters of Kushnabh). Now a
> day it is known as KANNAUJ.The native Brahmins of  this land were
> later known as KANYAKUBJA Brahmins.